# Accepting multiple unknown props for more than one child in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have multiple layers of components and want to pass multiple values from the top component down to the bottom component. I am trying to make the middle and bottom component as flexible as possible so I didn't explicitly write out each parameter it can accept. How could I achieve this? Thanks.

```js
...
export const Top = () => {
    return(
        <Middle
            botA={propA = true, propB = false} // Props cannot be
            botB={propA = 1, propB = 2}        // passed like this
        />
    );
}
```

```js
...
export const Middle = ({botA, botB}) => {
    return(
        <BottomA {...botA} />
        <BottomB {...botB} />
    );
}
```

```js
...
export const BottomA = ({...unknownProps}) => {
    // Do something with unknownProps
    return(
        ...
    );
}
```

```js
...
export const BottomB = ({...unknownProps}) => {
    // Do something with unknownProps
    return(
        ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Why would `BottomA` or `BottomB` not know what props they use? Just apply the same pattern you did above them, i.e. destructure the known props they need and spread the rest in to the `unknownProps` prop and do whatever needs to be done with them. Do you have a specific issue?

Comment: Sorry, edited with hopefully more clarity

Comment: All looks fine other than the original prop specification. Is this your question? How to pass an object as a prop? Example: `botA={{ propA: true, propB: false }}`

Comment: It's how to pass a list of props to a component that forwards them to another component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question appears to be about how to specify a props object to be passed as a prop itself. First, specify an object with the props to be passed on to the component, and second, pass this object as a prop to the middle component.

```
export const Top = () => {
  return(
    <Middle
      botA={{ propA: true, propB: false }}
      botB={{ propA: 1, propB: 2 }}
    />
  );
}
```

The middle child destructures the props and then spreads them into the appropriate child component.

```
export const Middle = ({ botA, botB }) => {
  return(
    <BottomA {...botA} /> // ...{ propA: true, propB: false }
    <BottomB {...botB} /> // ...{ propA: 1, propB: 2 }
  );
}
```

Child components destructure the props they know about, spread the rest into a prop, i.e. one you are calling `unknownProps`.

```
export const BottomA = ({ propA, propB, ...unknownProps }) => {
  return(
    ...
  );
}
```

If you find yourself continually passing props like this through intermediate components, a problem known as "props drilling", then you may want to explore the React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). This is an API and design pattern to resolve/alleviate the issue of explicit/implicit passing of props to intermediate components that don't know about them, and frankly probably shouldn't.

> #### Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.
>
> In a typical React application, data is passed top-down (parent to
> child) via props, but such usage can be cumbersome for certain types
> of props (e.g. locale preference, UI theme) that are required by many
> components within an application. Context provides a way to share
> values like these between components without having to explicitly pass
> a prop through every level of the tree.